# ORMLite ForeignCollections

Tags: java, foreign-keys, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a problem and I just do not know how to solve it. 
I want to model in JAVA a structure like: **Companies**, **Events** and **Locations**.

- Each Company includes one or many Location/s which represents the places where a branch of the company is
- Each event also has a Location where the event takes place

Here's the code:

```
public class Event {
    int id;
    String name;
    Location location;
    ...
}

public class Location {
    int id;
    String name;
    String building;
    ...
}

public class Company {
    int id;
    String name;
    Collection<Location> locations;
    ...
}
```

My problem is that i want to use ORMLite for saving the objects in a Database. But if I understood the foreign things in ORMLite correctly, i have to add a Company instance variable to the Location:

```
public class Location {
  @DatabaseField(columnName = "com_id", foreign = true)
  Company company;
  @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "loc_id")
  int id;
  @DatabaseField(columnName = "loc_name")
  String name;
  @DatabaseField(columnName = "loc_build")
  String building;
  ...
}

public class Company {
  @DatabaseField(columnName = "com_id")
  int id;
  @DatabaseField(columnName = "com_name")
  String name;
  @ForeignCollectionField()
  Collection<Location> locations;
  ...
}
```

But now the Location doesn't work for the Events!?! How can I implement such a behaviour?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you need to assign "ownership" of a `Location` by a `Company`.  You can do this in (at least) 2 different ways.

1. As you mentioned, you can have a `Location` has a `Company` field.  This would work fine if there was a one-to-one relationship there.  It would not work if you are trying to have one `"Pittsburgh"` `Location` and you want both `"Alcoa"` and `"US Steel"` companies having a location in Pittsburgh.
2. The 2nd way to implement it is to have a `CompanyLocation` entity which is often called a join-table in ORM languages.  ORMLite does not make this join table for you however.

   ```
   public class CompanyLocation {
      @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
      Company company;
      @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
      Location location;
   }
   ```

   So if want `"Alcoa"` to have a `Location` of `"Pittsburgh"` you need to insert a `CompanyLocation` into the table which defines the relationship.

Hope this helps.